# Moderncv compile error using \cventry - "Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition"

Tags: moderncv

I have the latest (moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0) version of moderncv but when compiling a minimal (half working) environment with my TexLive installation using pdflatex the cventries aren't correct and the compiler raise alerts as described below, a very MWE (50% working) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, draft, sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{red}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{My}{Name}
\address{Address}{City}
\phone[fixed]{12345}
\email{something@something.com}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

This yields the relevant error:

```
! Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> \@startpbox {
                             l@{\extracolsep {\fill }}r}
l.25 ...tution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

?
```

Which in the compiled PDF is rendered as: [image: compiled PDF]

I've tried to googled and browse for related issues but didn't found any relevant\similar question. I didn't dig into the moderncv style files as my LaTeX knowledge is limited. How should I act to solve this issue and compile correctly the document?

### The whole console log, if of any interest

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./CV.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/tweaklist.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvcollection.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvcompatibility.sty))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgpagella.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty))))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.te
x)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
))) (d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadiii',
               but the package provides `moderncvheadiii'.

) (d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvbodyiii.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii',
               but the package provides `moderncvbodyiii'.

(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/t1qpl.fd)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesometwo.fd)))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvcolorred.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def))
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)) (./CV.aux)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

Package microtype Warning: `draft' option active.
(microtype)                Disabling all micro-typographic extensions.
(microtype)                This might lead to different line and page breaks.

(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Package hyperref Warning: Draft mode on.

(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/qpl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbullet' on input line 19.

(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd)
(d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--19

! Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> \@startpbox {
                             l@{\extracolsep {\fill }}r}
l.25 ...tution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

?
```

### The errors log

```
Errors: 2, Warnings: 7, Bad boxes: 2


CV.tex
25
Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> \@startpbox {
                             l@{\extracolsep {\fill }}r}
l.25 ...tution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

CV.tex
25
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@mkpream ...after \@startpbox \expandafter {#1}}}
                                                  \let \@endpbox \relax \let...
l.25 ...tution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

moderncvheadiii.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadiii', but the package provides `moderncvheadiii'.

moderncvbodyiii.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii', but the package provides `moderncvbodyiii'.

CV.tex

Package microtype Warning: `draft' option active. Disabling all micro-typographic extensions. This might lead to different line and page breaks.

CV.tex

Package hyperref Warning: Draft mode on.

CV.tex
19
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/qpl/m/n' undefined using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead for symbol `textbullet' on input line 19.

CV.tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

CV.tex

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

CV.tex
19
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--19

CV.tex
25
Overfull \hbox (22.48833pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 25--25
[][] |
```

Comment: Update the colortbl package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've update it and the colortbl is now at the latest version https://i.imgur.com/8yS85bo.png however the console log is identical.

Comment: colortab is not colortbl.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh, you are right... *facepalm* How did you tell that the package needed to be updated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I totally agree then that this question can be closed permanently.

Comment: You may even need to install `colortbl`. For some reason it doesn't conplain about it as missing, but won't compile if it's absent -.-